# Examples of contraction mapping’s on the Euclidean spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If $(M,d)$ is a metric space, we say that $T:M\to M$ is a contraction if  $d(T(x),T(y))\le d(x,y)$.

The question seems simple however I’ve not been able to furnish examples for the following contraction mappings on the Euclidean spaces which

1) which has no fixed points

2) which has infinitely many fixed points

3) has exactly 2 fixed points.

For the second case, the identity mapping seems to work, but I’m not sure. Any hints or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you define contraction mapping?

Comment: T is a contraction if d(T(x),T(y))<=d(x,y) for all x and y belonging to the metric space.

Comment: @HEIFETZ that is definitely not my definition, so it may be worth stating that in your post

Comment: But the space you have given is not euclidean. It is also not complete btw.

Comment: The space has to be strictly a euclidean space.

Comment: For the first it is sufficient to take a translation, for the second the identity is a good example. The third is a bit more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

For 1) a tranlsation works, for 2) the identity works. 3) is not possible:

Claim: The fixed locus of a contraction of an Euclidean space is convex.

Proof. Suppose $x,z$ are two fixed points for a contraction $T$ of an Euclidean space $E$. Let $y$ be a point in the segment $[x,z]$. By triangular inequality and by contrcactivity we have $$ d(y,x)+d(y,z)\geq d(T(y),x)+d(T(y),z)\geq d(x,z)=d(x,y)+d(y,z)$$

hence $d(T(y),x)+d(T(y),z)=d(y,x)+d(y,z)$. If $d(T(y),x)<d(y,x)$ then $d(T(y),z)>d(y,z)$, contradicting the contracion hypothesis. Thus
$d(T(y),x)=d(y,x)$ and $d(T(y),z)=d(y,z)$ and this, in a Euclidean space, forces $T(y)=y$. So the whole segment $[x,z]$ is point-wise fixed by $T$.